# Como saber se um objeto é um array em javascript (sem jquery)?

Tags: javascript, array

Gostaria de saber como posso identificar que um objeto é ou não um `array` no Javascript.

Eu sei que no jQuery existe a função `$.isArray`. Porém gostaria de aprender a fazer isso sem o `jQuery`.

Tentei pelo `typeof` e não retornou o resultado esperado.

Exemplo:

```
typeof([]) // "object"
```

Comment: +1 pelo sem jQuery :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

O método Array.isArray() retorna true se um objeto é uma array, e false se não é.

Exemplo: `Array.isArray([]);`

Fonte: http://phpdojo.com.br/javascript/arrays-e-objetos-em-javascript/

```js
// Antipadrão
frutas = new Array('banana', 'laranja', 'uva');
 
// Padrão Literal
frutas = ['banana', 'laranja', 'uva'];

//Usando o operador typeof podemos verificar o tipo retornado para a variável, e //conforme disse anteriormente, em Javascript um array é um objeto. Veja abaixo:

alert(typeof frutas); // object

//E usando o método isArray podemos verificar se o objeto é um array:

alert(Array.isArray(frutas)); // true
```

> O typeof é um Operador Unário do JavaScript. Trocando em miúdos, é um
>   método nativo no JavaScript que retorna o tipo de um Operando.

Answer (score 5):

Pode tentar fazer assim:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call( list ) === '[object Array]' )
```

vai retornar True ou False

Comment: `[] instanceof Array` funcionaria?

Comment: Sim, se você user `list instanceof Array` tambem vai te retornar True ou False

Answer (score 4):

Outra forma:

```
[].constructor === Array
```